# Ansible: Do something when package version greater or equals

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a problem with running a task only when the package it requires has the correct version. In my example it is the OpenSSH Server. Only on 6.5 or greater the ed25519 host key can generated.

Here my tasks:

```
- name: ensure openssh-server is present
  apt:
    pkg: openssh-server
    state: latest
    install_recommends: no
    force: yes
    default_release: "{{ sshd_apt_backports_distribution }}"
  notify: restart sshd

- name: ensure ed25519 host key is present
  command: ssh-keygen -q -t ed25519 -N "" -f ssh_host_ed25519_key
  args:
    chdir: /etc/ssh
    creates: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

The error:

```
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["ssh-keygen", "-q", "-t", "ed25519", "-N", "", "-f", "ssh_host_ed25519_key"], "delta": "0:00:00.012330", "end": "2015-05-17 12:16:51.062852", "rc": 1, "start": "2015-05-17 12:16:51.050522", "warnings": []}
stderr: unknown key type ed25519
```

The second task should only triggered, when OpenSSH 6.5 or greater is present. You can see [here](https://github.com/systemli/ansible-sshd) my build is failing because the Travis CI tests run under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and there is no actual OpenSSH version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two steps.

First register the openssh-server version:

```
- name: Get openssh-server version
  shell: 'dpkg -s openssh-server | grep "^Version" | sed -re "s/^.*:([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/"'
  register: openssh_version
```

Then create the key if needed:

```
- name: ensure ed25519 host key is present
  command: ssh-keygen -q -t ed25519 -N "" -f ssh_host_ed25519_key
  args:
    chdir: /etc/ssh
    creates: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
  when: openssh_version.stdout | version_compare('6.5', '>=')
```

I have not tested, so YMMV, but it should be close to what you need.
There might be a simpler way to check openssh-server version too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works (after I changed the quotes)

Comment: Yep, I use it here: https://github.com/systemli/ansible-sshd/commit/9292c2fcaa00eb31a03532cf3f9e4f38c158c243

Answer (score 0):

A little follow-up for the previous answer, you don't need to grep or sed the result of dpkg, the command dpkg-query has a --showformat option to get exactly the information you want:

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat '${Version}' openssh-server
```

So you can use it with the simple command module:

```
- name: Get openssh-server version
  command: /usr/bin/dpkg-query --show --showformat ${Version} openssh-server
  register: openssh_version
```

Comment: Probably this could be a comment on the original answer, rather than a new answer.

Comment: This command will return "1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8", which is useless for a version_compare.